# Casting a field to XML, querying it returns NULL records

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I've a field on my table that is nvarchar(max) and contains XML document. Don't ask why it is nvarchar(max) instead of XML because I don't know it.
By the way, here is an extraction of a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ItemType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AutoPay xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">true</AutoPay>
  <Country xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">IT</Country>
  <Currency xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">EUR</Currency>
  <HitCounter xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">BasicStyle</HitCounter>
  <ListingDuration xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">GTC</ListingDuration>
  <ListingType xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
  <Location xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Italy</Location>
  <PaymentMethods xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">PayPal</PaymentMethods>
  <PayPalEmailAddress xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">email@paypal.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
  <PrimaryCategory xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <CategoryID>137084</CategoryID>
  </PrimaryCategory>
  <ShippingDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ShippingServiceOptions>
      <ShippingService>StandardShippingFromOutsideUS</ShippingService>
      <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="EUR">0</ShippingServiceCost>
      <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="EUR">0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
      <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
    </ShippingServiceOptions>
    <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
      <ShippingService>StandardInternational</ShippingService>
      <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="EUR">0</ShippingServiceCost>
      <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="EUR">0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
      <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
      <ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>
      <ShipToLocation>Europe</ShipToLocation>
    </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
    <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
    <InsuranceDetails>
      <InsuranceFee currencyID="EUR">0</InsuranceFee>
      <InsuranceOption>NotOffered</InsuranceOption>
    </InsuranceDetails>
    <InternationalInsuranceDetails>
      <InsuranceFee currencyID="EUR">0</InsuranceFee>
      <InsuranceOption>NotOffered</InsuranceOption>
    </InternationalInsuranceDetails>
  </ShippingDetails>
  <Site xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">US</Site>
  <Storefront xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <StoreCategoryID>2947535016</StoreCategoryID>
    <StoreCategory2ID>0</StoreCategory2ID>
  </Storefront>
  <DispatchTimeMax xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">4</DispatchTimeMax>
  <ReturnPolicy xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
    <Description>Accepted</Description>
    <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
  </ReturnPolicy>
  <ConditionID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">1000</ConditionID>
</ItemType>
```

I would love to query the table on that field, for example to extract CategoryID field.
I tried everything I knew, like casting to ntext, removing utf-16, replacing it with utf-8, adding namespaces and stuff like that, but the result is always a NULL record.

Here is one of the queries I tried:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' AS ns, 
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd)
select CategoryVal = CONVERT(xml, [Template]).value('(/ItemType/PrimaryCategory/CategoryID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM Templates where ID = 1
```

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
with xmlnamespaces('urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' as n)
select cast(Template as xml).value('(/ItemType/n:PrimaryCategory/n:CategoryID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from Templates 
where ID = 1
```

You need to prefix the elements in your xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that once, but **without the use of namespaces**.

I had my input as varchar(max) (nvarchar should work too)

```
@Text AS varchar(MAX)
```

Then i used an XML type variable and the conversion was as simple as this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = @Text
```

To query your CategoryID value you would use:

```
SELECT itemtype.item.value('(/ItemType/PrimaryCategory/CategoryID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')    
FROM @XML.nodes('/ItemType') AS itemtype(item);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Chrisopher, Mikael's answer worked exactly as requested!